# Session Management between different Web Services

Tags: web-services, session-cookies

I have three web services deployed on three different clouds.

Client only knows regarding the Web Service 1 :

1. Client calls the web service 1
2. Web service 1 calls Web service 2
3. Web service 2 calls Web Service 3

[image]

**I have to decide how can we manage client's session information in this architecture.**

**Any Suggestions please.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of question is generally offtopic in SO.

Session management (Whether on a single server, cluster or entirely disparate systems) are in place because we don't want our users to pass around their identifying information or credentials every time they request a new page. So what we essentially do is tell the client (or the browser in this case) to send us a identifier (cookie / session Id) everytime a new page is requested and we know the user profile mapped to that identifier on our end. i.e. Session Management allows us to Authenticate once for multiple transactions between the client and server.

What I infer from the problem statement is that the client will send a request once to the Service 1 and get a response back from the same service. This is not a candidate for session management. And you can always pass around client identifiers across services.

However, if you wish to allow the client to authenticate once and call the service multiple times, just give them an identifier on authentication which they will pass along with the service call, and you use that identifier just like a session ID.